# html canvas transform ? is it only: first do the transform, and then you draw into the canvas? Not, stick an image or etc on canvas, and transform it?

Tags: html, canvas

My goal is to bring in an image on to part of the canvas, then  scale it, move/translate it, and optionally skew it, also rotate and make alpha changes, kind of the primary "2d image manipulations", in an animated form, which is: do little changes over time from the starting state to the target end state.

Well, I figured to be efficient, I should use the canvas/2d context transform, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/transform -- as it does the first 3: scale, move/translate, and skew, "all in one."  I did half that code, and now I'm looking at examples and seeking to debug it.  All the examples I see, are do 1) some transform, away from the "unity transform":

```
   { a:1, b:0, c: 0, d:1, e:0, f:0 }; // this basic transform does nothing
```

and then *2)* draw into that.  But that's the opposite order from what I want: which is draw on the canvas (the image), and then do an animation over time using the above primary changes (scale, translate, skew, rotate, and alpha).  My question is: does it only "work this way", meaning I must setup the (single) transformation on the page first, and then "draw into that?"

I hope not ... that won't give me what I want, and I have to "ditch it", and go to 5 individual "transformations."  Comments?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that only works this way, canvas transforms and compositing mode and filters and lineWidth and fillStyle etc. properties are only applied to the next drawing operations.

The canvas itself only holds pixels information, it has no concept of drawn object. Your js code has to do this part.

So for what you wish, you can simply redraw everything every time:

1. reset the transform so we can clear `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);`
2. Clear the canvas `ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height)`
3. Set the transform to your new matrix `ctx.translate(x,y); ctx.scale(s)...`
4. Draw your transformed graphics `ctx.fill(); ctx.drawImage(...`
5. Wait next frame to do it again `requestAnimationFrame(update)`

Comment: This "hurts my head a little", because I want to run the animations backward when they rewind -- I'm building a player, where the "images" hold both text and images, not just "pictures", conveying information very nicely. And when they rewind, I want to go "backward" at a speed of 3-5 times.  Here's my question: in your opinion, do you feel like doing the 3 separate ctx ops: scale, translate, and skew (which rare), so really mostly 2 (scale and translate), is significantly LESS efficient then the transform?  If not sufficiently less efficient, I'm "dumping the transform".  Comments please ...

Comment: It's a lot easier to think of it, and potentially debug it the other way, I think I went down the wrong road ... ?

Comment: transform functions will have really little performance impacts. Don't bother calculating the whole matrix unless it's a measured bottleneck in your code. From your question it seems you are still very far from being able to measure anything.

Comment: You're right, good point: optimize for performance after.  So, one more thing Kaiido, thoughts/comments please?  So ever use powerpoint?  You've "slides plus animations?"  I'm doing something similar: lowest layer is (changing) background, layer above stuff moving in, and a layer where they get to put in information (not a canvas), and a layer above controls that can move, and some other stuff, it's variable. Please think of a stack of layers, just like you would use in gimp/photoshop.  Should this all "work fine", meaning a stack of stuff, nothing "super fast", it's not a game.  Thoughts?

Comment: Yes it should all work fine. Note that you can even handle layers nicely by using multiple canvases at the same time, and combine them all on a single visible one using `drawImage(canvas, x, y)`. If you have some layers that don't change, this will improve perfs a lot.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not getting you.  So yes, the canvases are layered in a stack, all the same size=screen-size.  Does the browser "graphics engine" simply naturally combine them in Z order?  Do I need to do something else "special beyond that?" yeah -- I think I got you, please confirm it's a "freebie" with the browser engine ... thanks